# Starting intent using adb on Workprofile enabled phone

Tags: android, adb

Has anyone tried starting intent using adb, but for  work profile user?

I am trying to start an intent using following command line,

adb shell  am start --user 11 -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.myapp.com/link" com.myapp

I have verified I have user 11 using command "adb shell pm list users"

It always give me this error:

Exception occurred while executing 'start':
**java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 11**
com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$LocalService.handleIncomingUser:16702 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.handleIncomingUser:1640 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAndWait:1488
    at com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser(UserController.java:2254)

Note this works just fine if I skip the "--user" directive, but I am trying to test something under android work profile, hence the question.